# PHP AES256 PKCS7 decryption from iOS Swift

Tags: php, swift, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'am trying to encrypt a string in Swift, and decrypt it in PHP. I have gotten some good help from SO, and hopefully someone can help once again. 
Here is the code I am trying to use in PHP for decryption.

```
$key = "test";
$pass = "bLOKONASw8tE2cki5QhkcA==";
$iv = "1234567890123456";   

$base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;
echo "pass: ".$pass;

$res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

$decrypted = $res_non;
echo " 1: ".$decrypted;
$dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);
echo " 2: ".$dec_s2;
$padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
echo " padding: ".$padding;
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
echo " Decrypted: ".$decrypted;
```

The string is encrypted in Swift, and I base64 encode it before I send it to the server.

I am not getting an error, but it seems like the resulting "decrypted" value is empty.
I have a test decryption function in Swift, which gives back the the correct output.

```
Key:<74657374 73747269 6e67>
Iv:<31323334 35363738 39303132 33343536>
Message: <74657374 6d657373 616765>
ivLength    = 16, ivData    = <31323334 35363738 39303132 33343536>
encryptedData: <6cb38a38 d012c3cb 44d9c922 e5086470>
base64cryptString = bLOKONASw8tE2cki5QhkcA==
```

If someone can help me figure out where I am going wrong, it would be ap

Comment: check you're padding I had this issue going to c# a while ago turns out the padding bytes are different php uses true nulls other languages use zero's or tabs etc.  I ended up having to do some work around code that was offensively long.  Also if they were padding to 16 bytes in php and c# runs to 64 bytes I think I had to allow for that too.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you ended up fixing the issue?

Comment: Its been like 5 years since I did it and don't have the code to hand I do remember something like having to set pkcs pack size to something silly like 9 to give equivilent of 7 in c# I'll see if I still have the client code archived off somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of initialize vector must be 16 bytes in AES - CBC mode.

Comment: I have corrected the blocksize, making it 16bytes. However, now I'm not getting a result at the end. I've updated the code to reflect the changes. Previously I was told I need to remove the PKCS7 padding, which is what a part of the code is supposed to do. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, without any codes to encrypt, only I can do is guessing.
If you want to encrypt using AES256 with CCCrypto, your key size must be exactly 32bytes.
If you'd like to use variable length key, try to use Blowfish algorithm, my recommendation.

I wrote a blog about this, so please take a look.
http://blog.s21g.com/articles/2382
In this example, I truncate key size to match AES specification.

Comment: I've looked at your article, and while I do appreciate the help, I am unable to figure out how to use it. Do you have a working example of the Blowfish? Thank you, again.

Comment: func
UTF8Data( p: String ) -> NSData? {

 return p.dataUsingEncoding( NSUTF8StringEncoding )

}



let wKey = UTF8Data( "teststring" )!

let wIV = UTF8Data( "12345678" )!

// Encryption

var ( s, data ) = DataEncryptedByBlowfish( UTF8Data( "testmessage" )!, wKey, CCOptions( kCCOptionPKCS7Padding ), wIV )

// Decryption

( s, data ) = DataDecryptedByBlowfish( data, wKey, CCOptions( kCCOptionPKCS7Padding ), wIV )